Windows C++ API ReadFile stuck, doesnt return
I'm trying to copy a file from a Linux server to a local Windows machine using PSCP. Added code below for the same.
I'm facing an issue that ReadFile() is blocked in some use-cases. ReadFile() doesn't return if the /home/user/testzero.cmd file is 0 bytes, but works fine if it has any data. Any idea why this would happen?
If CloseHandle(hWritePipe); is called before ReadFile()(i dont want to do this as i would want to check for copy status/error/asks for password, then do WriteFile(), and read again), it works fine.
I couldn't get this working in case of an empty file.
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define BUFSIZE 4096

int main() {
  // Command to execute (adjust paths and options as needed)
  
  LPCTSTR commandLine = TEXT("D:\\tools\\pscp.exe -scp -2 user@linuxserver:'/home/user/testzero.cmd' D:\\Tools\\ProcessExplorer\\testzero.cmd");


  // Initialize structures for CreateProcess parameters
  STARTUPINFO si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
  HANDLE hReadPipe = NULL, hWritePipe = NULL;
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];
  DWORD bytesRead;
  BOOL bSuccess;

  ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
  sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
  sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

  // Create a pipe for the child process's stdout
  if (!CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &sa, 0)) {
    std::cerr << "CreatePipe failed. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // Ensure the command line string is writable
  wchar_t* writableCommandLine = _wcsdup(commandLine);

  ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  si.hStdError = hWritePipe;
  si.hStdOutput = hWritePipe;
  si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

  // Create the process
  if (!CreateProcess(NULL, writableCommandLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create process. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
    CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
    free(writableCommandLine);
    return 1;
  }

  // Read output from the pipe
  while (true) {
    bSuccess = ReadFile(hReadPipe, buffer, BUFSIZE, &bytesRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess || bytesRead == 0) break;
    std::string output(buffer, bytesRead);
    std::cout << output;
  }
  
  // Close process and thread handles
  CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

  // Close the read end of the pipe
  CloseHandle(hReadPipe);

  // Free the allocated memory
  free(writableCommandLine);

  return 0;
}


Any idea why this would happen - because it's documented to happen? How would you expect to use ReadFile if it didn't wait until something appears in an empty pipe?

How can i handle this situation, the empty also copies fine but ReadFile doesnt return

When you say the empty copies fine, what exactly do you mean - are you saying the destination file entry is created? If so that doesn't mean anything copies fine. That's like putting an empty bucket next to another empty bucket, and saying the empty copied fine.

Close a write end pipe. Or create a simple data protocol, say first 8 bytes are the data length.

@3CxEZiVlQ , i may not want to close write end pipe, because i want to enter password if it asks for. also need to read the file copy progress

@DanChase, thanks i understand your point, is it possible to set the timeout in this case?

@madoverdose see the documentation, you are missing some steps in your pipe management.

"i may not want to close write end pipe, because i want to enter password if it asks for. also need to read the file copy progress " You don't need the write end pipe for either of those things. For the first, you need a second pipe pair for stdin. For the second, you are still reading from the read end of the pipe. The outstanding write end pipe means that the read cannot fail with "broken pipe".

Does this answer your question? Win32 ReadFile hangs when reading from pipe

@RaymondChen, closing the write handle amkes ReadFile return, but i don't want closing since i would write the password on prompt and the child process cannot write again as the write handle is closed. Anyway i figured out the solution for my problem. Thank you

If you want to write the password on prompt, you don't write it to the stdout write handle. You need to create a new pipe, connect the read end to the child's stdin, and you write to the write end of the new pipe. (Writing to the write end of your pipe just makes the data come out the read end. The child process never sees what you wrote to that pipe.)

Yes that's what I'm doing

Issue is with pscp not printing any status in case of an empty file, so no output from pscp , so using pscp with verbose works fine.
LPCTSTR commandLine = TEXT("D:\\tools\\pscp.exe -scp -2 -v user@linuxserver:'/home/user/testzero.cmd' D:\\Tools\\ProcessExplorer\\testzero.cmd");

